# Format currency in Java

Tags: java, currency

Given the following code.

```
DecimalFormat formatter = (DecimalFormat) NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(new Locale("en", "UK"));
DecimalFormatSymbols symbols = formatter.getDecimalFormatSymbols();

symbols.setCurrencySymbol("");
formatter.setDecimalFormatSymbols(symbols);
formatter.setCurrency(Currency.getInstance("GBP"));

System.out.println(formatter.format(new BigDecimal("123.45")));
```

It displays `GBP123.45`.

Can this code be modified to display it in the `123.45 GBP` format (in reverse order with a space between the number and its code)?

Comment: Any reason you're using en-UK rather than en-GB? To be honest, if you're going to mess around with every aspect of the formatting, why not just do it manually?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you just need to set the pattern to use. Going from memory (ie I didn't code this up) it would be DecimalFormat.applyPattern("#,##0.00 ¤");.

Comment: See Pattterns in http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html